# What is hp_metric in TensorBoard and how to get rid of it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I am new to Tensorboard.

I am using fairly simple code running an experiment, and this is the output:

[image]

I don't remember asking for a `hp_metric` graph, yet here it is.

**What is it and how do I get rid of it?**

---

Full code to reproduce, using Pytorch Lightning (not that I think anyone should have to reproduce this to answer):

Please notice the ONLY line dereferencing TensorBoard is

```
self.logger.experiment.add_scalars("losses", {"train_loss": loss}, global_step=self.current_epoch)
```

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from typing import List, Optional
from pytorch_lightning.core.lightning import LightningModule
from Testing.Research.toy_datasets.ClustersDataset import ClustersDataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from Testing.Research.config.ConfigProvider import ConfigProvider
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer, seed_everything
from torch import optim
import os
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger


class VAEFC(LightningModule):
    # see https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-variational-autoencoders-vaes-f70510919f73
    # for possible upgrades, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02282.pdf
    # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332179/how-to-weight-kld-loss-vs-reconstruction-loss-in-variational-auto-encoder
    def __init__(self, encoder_layer_sizes: List, decoder_layer_sizes: List, config):
        super(VAEFC, self).__init__()
        self._config = config
        self.logger: Optional[TensorBoardLogger] = None

        assert len(encoder_layer_sizes) >= 3, "must have at least 3 layers (2 hidden)"
        # encoder layers
        self._encoder_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(1, len(encoder_layer_sizes) - 1):
            enc_layer = nn.Linear(encoder_layer_sizes[i - 1], encoder_layer_sizes[i])
            self._encoder_layers.append(enc_layer)

        # predict mean and covariance vectors
        self._mean_layer = nn.Linear(encoder_layer_sizes[
                                         len(encoder_layer_sizes) - 2],
                                     encoder_layer_sizes[len(encoder_layer_sizes) - 1])
        self._logvar_layer = nn.Linear(encoder_layer_sizes[
                                           len(encoder_layer_sizes) - 2],
                                       encoder_layer_sizes[len(encoder_layer_sizes) - 1])

        # decoder layers
        self._decoder_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(1, len(decoder_layer_sizes)):
            dec_layer = nn.Linear(decoder_layer_sizes[i - 1], decoder_layer_sizes[i])
            self._decoder_layers.append(dec_layer)

        self._recon_function = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')

    def _encode(self, x):
        for i in range(len(self._encoder_layers)):
            layer = self._encoder_layers[i]
            x = F.relu(layer(x))

        mean_output = self._mean_layer(x)
        logvar_output = self._logvar_layer(x)
        return mean_output, logvar_output

    def _reparametrize(self, mu, logvar):
        if not self.training:
            return mu
        std = logvar.mul(0.5).exp_()
        if std.is_cuda:
            eps = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(std.size()).normal_()
        else:
            eps = torch.FloatTensor(std.size()).normal_()
        reparameterized = eps.mul(std).add_(mu)
        return reparameterized

    def _decode(self, z):
        for i in range(len(self._decoder_layers) - 1):
            layer = self._decoder_layers[i]
            z = F.relu((layer(z)))

        decoded = self._decoder_layers[len(self._decoder_layers) - 1](z)
        # decoded = F.sigmoid(self._decoder_layers[len(self._decoder_layers)-1](z))
        return decoded

    def _loss_function(self, recon_x, x, mu, logvar, reconstruction_function):
        """
        recon_x: generating images
        x: origin images
        mu: latent mean
        logvar: latent log variance
        """
        binary_cross_entropy = reconstruction_function(recon_x, x)  # mse loss TODO see if mse or cross entropy
        # loss = 0.5 * sum(1 + log(sigma^2) - mu^2 - sigma^2)
        kld_element = mu.pow(2).add_(logvar.exp()).mul_(-1).add_(1).add_(logvar)
        kld = torch.sum(kld_element).mul_(-0.5)
        # KL divergence Kullback–Leibler divergence, regularization term for VAE
        # It is a measure of how different two probability distributions are different from each other.
        # We are trying to force the distributions closer while keeping the reconstruction loss low.
        # see https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-variational-autoencoders-vaes-f70510919f73

        # read on weighting the regularization term here:
        # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332179/how-to-weight-kld-loss-vs-reconstruction-loss-in-variational
        # -auto-encoder
        return binary_cross_entropy + kld * self._config.regularization_factor

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_index):
        orig_batch, noisy_batch, _ = batch
        noisy_batch = noisy_batch.view(noisy_batch.size(0), -1)

        recon_batch, mu, logvar = self.forward(noisy_batch)

        loss = self._loss_function(
            recon_batch,
            orig_batch, mu, logvar,
            reconstruction_function=self._recon_function
        )
        # self.logger.experiment.add_scalars("losses", {"train_loss": loss})
        self.logger.experiment.add_scalars("losses", {"train_loss": loss}, global_step=self.current_epoch)
        # self.logger.experiment.add_scalar("train_loss", loss, self.current_epoch)
        self.logger.experiment.flush()
        return loss

    def train_dataloader(self):
        default_dataset, train_dataset, test_dataset = ClustersDataset.clusters_dataset_by_config()
        train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=self._config.batch_size, shuffle=True)
        return train_dataloader

    def test_dataloader(self):
        default_dataset, train_dataset, test_dataset = ClustersDataset.clusters_dataset_by_config()
        test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=self._config.batch_size, shuffle=True)
        return test_dataloader

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=self._config.learning_rate)
        return optimizer

    def forward(self, x):
        mu, logvar = self._encode(x)
        z = self._reparametrize(mu, logvar)
        decoded = self._decode(z)
        return decoded, mu, logvar


if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = ConfigProvider.get_config()
    seed_everything(config.random_seed)
    latent_dim = config.latent_dim
    enc_layer_sizes = config.enc_layer_sizes + [latent_dim]
    dec_layer_sizes = [latent_dim] + config.dec_layer_sizes
    model = VAEFC(config=config, encoder_layer_sizes=enc_layer_sizes, decoder_layer_sizes=dec_layer_sizes)

    logger = TensorBoardLogger(save_dir='tb_logs', name='VAEFC')
    logger.hparams = config  # TODO only put here relevant stuff
    # trainer = Trainer(gpus=1)
    trainer = Trainer(deterministic=config.is_deterministic,
                      #auto_lr_find=config.auto_lr_find,
                      #log_gpu_memory='all',
                      # min_epochs=99999,
                      max_epochs=config.num_epochs,
                      default_root_dir=os.getcwd(),
                      logger=logger
                      )
    # trainer.tune(model)
    trainer.fit(model)
    print("done training vae with lightning")
```

ClustersDataset.py

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import numpy as np
from Testing.Research.config.ConfigProvider import ConfigProvider


class ClustersDataset(Dataset):
    __default_dataset = None
    __default_dataset_train = None
    __default_dataset_test = None

    def __init__(self, cluster_size: int, noise_factor: float = 0, transform=None, n_clusters=2, centers_radius=4.0):
        super(ClustersDataset, self).__init__()
        self._cluster_size = cluster_size
        self._noise_factor = noise_factor
        self._n_clusters = n_clusters
        self._centers_radius = centers_radius
        # self._transform = transform
        self._size = self._cluster_size * self._n_clusters

        self._create_data_clusters()
        self._combine_clusters_to_array()
        self._normalize_data()
        self._add_noise()

        # self._plot()
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def clusters_dataset_by_config():
        if ClustersDataset.__default_dataset is not None:
            return \
                ClustersDataset.__default_dataset, \
                ClustersDataset.__default_dataset_train, \
                ClustersDataset.__default_dataset_test
        config = ConfigProvider.get_config()
        default_dataset = ClustersDataset(
            cluster_size=config.cluster_size,
            noise_factor=config.noise_factor,
            transform=None,
            n_clusters=config.n_clusters,
            centers_radius=config.centers_radius
        )
        
        train_size = int(config.train_size * len(default_dataset))
        test_size = len(default_dataset) - train_size
        train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(default_dataset, [train_size, test_size])

        ClustersDataset.__default_dataset = default_dataset
        ClustersDataset.__default_dataset_train = train_dataset
        ClustersDataset.__default_dataset_test = test_dataset

        return default_dataset, train_dataset, test_dataset

    def _create_data_clusters(self):
        self._clusters = [torch.zeros((self._cluster_size, 2)) for _ in range(self._n_clusters)]
        centers_radius = self._centers_radius
        for i, c in enumerate(self._clusters):
            r, x, y = 3.0, centers_radius * np.cos(i * np.pi * 2 / self._n_clusters), centers_radius * np.sin(
                i * np.pi * 2 / self._n_clusters)
            cluster_length = 1.1
            cluster_start = i * 2 * np.pi / self._n_clusters
            cluster_end = cluster_length * (i + 1) * 2 * np.pi / self._n_clusters
            cluster_inds = torch.linspace(start=cluster_start, end=cluster_end, steps=self._cluster_size,
                                          dtype=torch.float)
            c[:, 0] = r * torch.sin(cluster_inds) + y
            c[:, 1] = r * torch.cos(cluster_inds) + x

    def _plot(self):
        plt.figure()
        plt.scatter(self._noisy_values[:, 0], self._noisy_values[:, 1], s=1, color='b', label="noisy_values")
        plt.scatter(self._values[:, 0], self._values[:, 1], s=1, color='r', label="values")
        plt.legend(loc="upper left")
        plt.show()

    def _combine_clusters_to_array(self):
        size = self._size
        self._values = torch.zeros(size, 2)
        self._labels = torch.zeros(size, dtype=torch.long)
        for i, c in enumerate(self._clusters):
            self._values[i * self._cluster_size: (i + 1) * self._cluster_size, :] = self._clusters[i]
            self._labels[i * self._cluster_size: (i + 1) * self._cluster_size] = i

    def _add_noise(self):
        size = self._size

        mean = torch.zeros(size, 2)
        std = torch.ones(size, 2)
        noise = torch.normal(mean, std)
        self._noisy_values = torch.zeros(size, 2)
        self._noisy_values[:] = self._values
        self._noisy_values = self._noisy_values + noise * self._noise_factor

    def _normalize_data(self):
        values_min, values_max = torch.min(self._values), torch.max(self._values)
        self._values = (self._values - values_min) / (values_max - values_min)
        self._values = self._values * 2 - 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size  # number of samples in the dataset

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        item = self._values[index, :]
        noisy_item = self._noisy_values[index, :]
        # if self._transform is not None:
        #     noisy_item = self._transform(item)
        return item, noisy_item, self._labels[index]

    @property
    def values(self):
        return self._values

    @property
    def noisy_values(self):
        return self._noisy_values
```

Config values (ConfigProvider just returns those as an object)

```
num_epochs: 15
batch_size: 128
learning_rate: 0.0001
auto_lr_find: False

noise_factor: 0.1
regularization_factor: 0.0

cluster_size: 5000
n_clusters: 5
centers_radius: 4.0
train_size: 0.8

latent_dim: 8

enc_layer_sizes: [2, 200, 200, 200]
dec_layer_sizes: [200, 200, 200, 2]

retrain_vae: False
random_seed: 11
is_deterministic: True
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the default setting of tensorboard in pytorch lightning. You can set `default_hp_metric` to false to get rid of this metric.

```
TensorBoardLogger(save_dir='tb_logs', name='VAEFC', default_hp_metric=False)
```

The `hp_metric` helps you track the model performance across different hyperparameters. You can check it at `hparams` in your [tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2EoG.png).

Comment: what do you mean by "helps you"? All I can see is a graph with a single point.

Comment: What if we don't create a logger explicitly, but instead use the default `self.logger` that comes from subclassing `pl.LightningModule`? Also, what is this supposed to do? It's just -1 for all of my runs.

Comment: >what do you mean by "helps you"?

You can set the metric to log as documented at https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/logging.html?highlight=hp_metric#logging-hyperparameters 

Then, you can look through your hyperparameters and see which come out best according to whichever metric you choose.

Comment: @Pete If you formulate a stand-alone answer I will probably accept it

Answer (score 2):

`hp_metric` (hyperparameter metric) is to help you tune your hyperparameters.

You can set this metric to whatever you like as documented in [pytorch official docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/logging.html?highlight=hp_metric#logging-hyperparameters).

Then, you can look through your hyperparameters and see which come out best according to whichever metric you choose.

Alternatively, if you don't want it, you can disable it as suggested in @joe32140's answer:

> You can set default_hp_metric to false to get rid of this metric.
>
> ```
> TensorBoardLogger(save_dir='tb_logs', name='VAEFC', default_hp_metric=False)
> ```

Comment: I don't understand if or how this persists over several runs

Comment: @Gulzar since you are using pytorch-lightning, you should find that every time you do a training run, a new directory in the lightning_logs directory is created. Usually this is version_0, version_1, etc. 
When you run tensorboard and set --log_dir as the path to lightning_logs, you should see all runs in tensorboard. If you go to HParams page, each run is listed with the HParams you used (providing they were passed to the model as hparams dict/Namespace) along with the hp_metric result that was logged. See [docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/hyperparameters.html)

Comment: I know that, but this doesn't explain what the graph is. If every run has a single scalar, then what is the graph?

Comment: You will log the hp_metric each time you do validation, so the graph will show how your metric changes with respect to the step number. In your graph in the question it wasn't logged so you have a single point, but if you set it up as described you will see a time series of the metric throughout training for that run.

Comment: @Pete And how this time series help us to select hyperparameters? A single value of the metric in the whole validation set after training finishes will be a lot more informative imo. Any ideas how we can generate a single value at the end of the training?